# How to place an icon / image inside an UITextFIeld just next to the last letter of the text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uitextfield

I have a text field in which the value is populated with a string which I get from the server. I want to set an icon inside my text field just to show user that the text field is actually not a label but it can be edited. I went through other questions but only found answers for setting an icon on leftViewMode or RightViewMode. How can I achieve it ?

```
    _titleLabel.delegate = self;
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_Canvas_name"]];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [_titleLabel setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    [_titleLabel setRightView:imgView];
```

[image]

I want the image to be just after g in "Touch - Drawing".

Answer (score 1):

Write a method which will return your UITextField's text width. Then place the image just after that. Method will be like this,

```
- (float)textWidthOf:(UITextField *)textfield {
    CGSize textSize = [textfield.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textfield.font}];
    return textSize.width;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add button inside the text field and set frame or constraints according to that so you can get button next to "g" in "Touch - Drawing".

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

btn.frame = CGRectMake(self.yourTextField.bounds.size.width - 50, 5, 25, 25);

[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.yourTextField addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: please describe him whats constraint you give and how you set that so person understand.